# How can I track *complex* forex trades so I have an idea of my profit vs loss over time?

Tags: foreign-exchange, software, profitability, spreadsheet

What's the best way to keep track of my forex trades so that I can determine how profitable my trading has been?

I've been looking into trading foreign exchange currency pairs for profit, but before I get too ahead of myself I want to make sure I have all the tools I need to track my success.

I found guides on the internet for how to calculate profit/loss. It makes sense when you trade 100 EUR for USD and then trade those USD back again to EUR. But it seems wayy more complicated if you trade on a cascading set of limit orders of different quantities back-and-forth. And between different pairs.

How do forex traders keep track of their trades so they can, at an instant and over time, analyze how successful they've been?

Comment: is this any different from stock trading? Because I bet there's tools for stock trading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to tracking trade history with different quantities is to use [lots](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tax_lot).

Say your first order was to buy 100 EUR (paid with some amount of USD). For accounting purposes, we can place that buy order into `Lot #1`. This lot remains open until you've completed sell orders at least 100 EUR.

### Examples

Here's a few examples to show how Lots can be opened with buy orders, and closed with a set (or fraction) of sell order(s).

##### Example 1: Sell 100 EUR

The easiest case possible is when you sell exactly the amount of EUR that you bought -- in this case, 100 EUR. When you put this 100 EUR sell order in `Lot #1` it's closed.

You can now calculate the profit of `Lot #1` based on [a] how much USD you bought the 100 EUR for and [b] how much you got when you sold the 100 EUR.

##### Example 2: Sell 50 EUR Twice

A slightly more complicated example is where you sold exactly half the amount of EUR that you bought -- in this case, two sell orders of 50 EUR. When you put both of these 50 EUR sell orders in your `Lot #1`, it's closed (because the total amount sold equals the total amount bought in this lot).

Again, you can use the three orders to calculate the profit of `Lot #1`.

##### Example 3: Sell unequal amounts

As time goes on, you may find yourself in a situation where you can't stuff your most-recent sell orders into your most-recent open Lot.

Let's you sold 40 EUR three times. In this case, the first two orders combined (40+40=80 EUR) don't match the most-recent buy (100 EUR), and the third exceeds it (40*3=120 EUR).

Of course, the solution is to fill `Lot #42` with a fraction of the third sell order. So you add the first two Sell 40 EUR sell orders to `Lot #42` and 50% of the third sell order to `Lot #42`. That closes out `Lot #42`, and you can calculate its profit.

The remaining half of the third sell order can be used to close the subsequent `Lot #43`.

### Software

While you *could* keep track of your lots with pen & paper or a spreadsheet, I prefer to use a tool that was designed for this.

There's many accounting & portfolio tracking apps for this, but personally I prefer [GNU Cash](https://www.gnucash.org/) -- which is free, has a great [community](https://lists.gnucash.org/mailman/listinfo/gnucash-user), great [documentation](https://gnucash-docs-rst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/C/ch_basics.html), and has a [great UI](https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Lots_GUI) for [manipulating lots](https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Concept_of_Lots).

### Conclusion

You can create and close lots however you want, but I usually just create one lot for every buy order and "close" each lot with the most-recent sell order. This is called [FIFO](https://www.marketbeat.com/financial-terms/cost-basis/).

Though "Tax Lots" are traditionally used for taxes, you can use this technique  to calculate your profitability over-time by just looking at your closed lots.

Comment: What about when you buy GPB with some of those EUR?

Comment: The realized forex price, or the unrealized current mark-to-market forex price, doesn't net rollover interest paid or received. To produce a perfect result, just from the currency prices, would require a basis adjustment. Well, a forex account might have daily statements with the rollover output separately.